# Can I make nan times 0 equal 0? How can I mask a DataArray?

Tags: python, numpy, mask, python-xarray

I have an xarray.DataArray, let's call it `height`, that I'm trying to reduce to represent only a desired region. For that, I have a second DataArray that is zero outside my region and a value up to one inside it, so when I multiply both DataArrays it makes everything zero but the desired region.

However, my `height` data isn't perfect and I have some nan values in the DataArray. I want to keep those nan values that are inside my region, but I don't care about the ones outside of it. I would like to multiply the DataArrays and get a zero for every nan*0 operation, but I'm currently getting a nan. Is there a way I can get zeroes from it, or is there a better way to make every element outside my region zero?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Every arithmetic operation using a nan always produces a nan.  That's a processor rule, not a Python rule.  You may be able to use `apply` to replace only the values you need.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do something with `np.where()` to accomplish this.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking about using where, but I don't know how to use the points where the mask is zero to apply something to the height, if I understand correctly then np.where() can only check conditions over the same array it is applied on.

Comment: I'm not a numpy expert, but it would help those who are if you showed sample code and how you want to use it.

Comment: You can try using [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html), it is a numpy func that can convert nan to 0.

Comment: @rr_goyal thanks! I went with a solution similar to this

Comment: Should I consider posting this as an answer for others to know what worked ?

Comment: @rr_goyal just posted the way I ended up solving it!

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following solution

```
height=height.fillna(-1)
height=height*mask
height=height.where(height<0)
```

Since the values on my height dataarray are always positive.